# Terminal hangs when executing yum commands

Tags: linux, command, yum, freeze

During a patch window, the `yum update` command stopped running with a Bus Error. Now when I try to execute a yum command my terminal hangs and I need to kill the process.

I have tried to kill all the yum commands running that showed with the `ps -aef | grep yum`, this did not help.
I have tried to `rm -f /var/run/yum.pid` and `rm -f /var/cache/yum`
Afterward, I ran the command `rpm --rebuilddb` after these commands yum still hangs and I need to kill the process.

No matter what yum command I use it hangs.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue (on Redhat 7). 
For me, this worked out:

```
sudo kill -9 $(ps aux | grep -E 'yum|rpm' | awk '{print $2}')
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/rpm/__db* /var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock
sudo rpm --rebuilddb
```

Be careful though, 'kill -9' is a bad way to stop processes. Especially recursive like the above.
Use the above as a last effort to overcome you issue, **after** you have examinated your processes running.